# Call Jasper subreports in java

Tags: java, subreports

I'm pretty familar with jasperstudio 6.3.0 and am able to run other reports from java with no problems.  Works well.  I am, however, not able to run a report that contains subreports.  I found solutions on here stackoverflow but still am unable to make it work.  In my solution, I am loading the reports into a table for storage and pulling the subreports and main report from the database and compiling the jrxml.  Everything works fine up to there and then

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at: subInvoiceSummary.jasper.
ERROR in runReport:Resource not found at: subInvoiceSummary.jasper.
at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getResourceFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:153)
at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getReport(RepositoryUtil.java:112)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.loadReport(JRFillSubreport.java:398)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateReport(JRFillSubreport.java:365)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:427)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:341)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:381)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:500)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2022)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:748)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:255)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:115)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:580)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:396)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:90)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:456)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:863)

I've tried a lot of permutations but to no avail.  I tried also to pull in the code for jasperreports to trace the the stack shown above but there are so many .jar dependencies and versions of dependencies I could not get it to compile clean in my project after 2 days (if anyone has a link to a simple method to make that work please let me know).  Here is the code snippet:

```
Map<String, Object> rptParms = new HashMap<String, Object>();

List<daRecOnDemandSubReport> subReports = report.getOnDemandSubReport();
Iterator<daRecOnDemandSubReport> subReportList = subReports.iterator();
while (subReportList.hasNext()) {
daRecOnDemandSubReport subReport = subReportList.next();
ByteArrayInputStream x = getSubReportDataStream(dbConnROIPro, report.getODReportID());
JasperReport compiledSubReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(x);
String fileName = subReport.getODSubReportFileName().replace(".jrxml", ".jasper");
rptParms.put(fileName, compiledSubReport);
}

ByteArrayInputStream x = getReportDataStream(dbConnROIPro, report.getODReportID());

JasperReport cRpt = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(x);

rptParms = getReportParameters(dbConnGTrack,report.getODReportID(), rptParms, report.getOnDemandParm(), programID);

JasperPrint rpt = JasperFillManager.fillReport(cRpt,rptParms,dbConnGTrack.getDbConn());

ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JRXlsxExporter XLSXexporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
   XLSXexporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(rpt));
   XLSXexporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outStream)); 
   XLSXexporter.exportReport();
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and never found a simple way to achieive this. Jasper developers themselves say subreports are not very well implemented on their forums.

I solved the issue with this code of mine. It's far from perfect either, but it works.

```
public byte[] generateReport(ExportType exportType, String resourceName, Connection connection, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws JRException, SQLException {
    JasperReport jasperReport = loadReport(resourceName);

    LOGGER.debug("Loading subreports if any...");
    Map<String, JasperReport> subReports = loadSubReports(resourceName, jasperReport);
    parameters.putAll(subReports);

    LOGGER.debug("Filling report with JDBC and {}", parameters);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, connection);

    LOGGER.debug("Exporting report with {}", exportType.getClass().getSimpleName());
    byte[] pdf = exportType.export(jasperPrint);

    return pdf;
}

/**
 * Converts a system resource into a JasperReport instance.
 * If the extension is ".jasper", it tries to load a pre-compiled report.
 * If the extension is ".jrxml", it tries to compile the report.
 */
private JasperReport loadReport(String resourceName) throws JRException {
    JasperReport jasperReport = null;
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);

    if (inputStream != null) {
        if (resourceName.toLowerCase().endsWith(JASPER)) {
            LOGGER.debug("Loading pre-compiled report: {}", resourceName);
            jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(inputStream);
        } else {
            LOGGER.debug("Compiling XML report: {}", resourceName);
            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
        }
    } else {
        LOGGER.warn("Unable to open resource: {}", resourceName);
    }
    return jasperReport;
}

/**
 * Parses a Report for SubReport parameters.
 * A Parameter has to be a <code>java.lang.Object</code> or a <code>net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport</code> to be considered a SubReport Input
 * An Object parameter has the advantage to allow Jasper Report's IDE to accept a Filename String resource.
 * If the parameter is an Object, the Filename declared as <b>default value</b> is used to load the SubReport.
 * If the parameter is a JasperReport, the parameter's name is used instead.
 * 
 * The default value, or the parameter's name, have to use a ".jasper" or ".jrxml" extension.
 * The SubReport resource's path has to be located relatively to the parent Report.
 */
private Map<String, JasperReport> loadSubReports(String masterResource, JasperReport jasperReport) throws JRException {
    Map<String, JasperReport> subReportExpressions = new HashMap<>();
    String masterPath = FilenameUtils.getFullPath(masterResource);

    for (JRParameter jrParameter : jasperReport.getParameters()) {
        String subReportName = getSubReportName(jrParameter);
        if (subReportName != null) {
            String name = jrParameter.getName();
            JasperReport subReport = loadReport(masterPath + subReportName);
            subReportExpressions.put(name, subReport);
        }
    }
    return subReportExpressions;
}


/**
 * Analyses the parameter to find a SubReport resource name respecting the defined rules
 * 
 * @return The filename of the resource, or null
 */
private String getSubReportName(JRParameter jrParameter) {
    String ret = null;
    Class<?> valueClass = jrParameter.getValueClass();
    boolean isObject = (valueClass == Object.class);
    boolean isJasperReport = (valueClass == JasperReport.class);

    // If the parameter is an Object,
    // we take the SubReport name from the default value (a String)
    if (isObject) {
        String defaultValue = getDefaultValue(jrParameter);
        if (defaultValue != null && checkExtension(defaultValue)) {
            ret = defaultValue;
        }
    }

    // If the parameter is a JasperReport, or an Object without a correct defaultValue,
    // we take the SubReport name from the parameter's name
    if (isJasperReport || (ret == null && isObject)) {
        String name = jrParameter.getName();
        if (checkExtension(name)) {
            ret = name;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}


private boolean checkExtension(String defaultValue) {
    defaultValue = defaultValue.toLowerCase();
    return defaultValue.endsWith(JRXML) || defaultValue.endsWith(JASPER);
}

private String getDefaultValue(JRParameter jrParameter) {
    String ret = null;
    JRExpression defaultValueExpression = jrParameter.getDefaultValueExpression();
    if (defaultValueExpression != null) {
        ret = defaultValueExpression.getText();
        if (ret != null && ret.length() > 2 && ret.startsWith(QUOTE) && ret.endsWith(QUOTE)) {
            // Removing quotes from the String
            ret = ret.substring(1, ret.length() - 1);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Hope this helps. I'll favorite your question, if anyone has a better solution.